# Using Python Flask, AngularJS, test/production directories and serving requests

Tags: python, angularjs, heroku, flask

Here is the setup:

Using ngBoilerplate (grunt, bower, angular, the works...) to create a SAP application. On my localhost, it launches a NodeJS server so I can test the app. This all works fine minus the database/apis. Using Grunt, it will create a /build folder (which is all the non-minified source,assets, for debugging) and a /bin folder with the production code.

For the backend I have a Python flask app (which I'll use for REST API's) on Heroku. Inside the main Python script:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    #index.html has the angular SAP
    return make_response( open('build/index.html').read() )
```

I push the code to Heroku, it detects a Python app (which I believe is good as I will need Python to make my api requests), and it serves the correct index.html. I see Angular making requests to /vendor/angular.js /css/angular.css etc, **when those files technically live in /build/vendor/angular.js.**

I'm not sure if I'm suppose to tell Angular where to grab the files or if it's Python related.

Am I suppose to change the DOCROOT (WWW) like in LAMP land?
Do I change the routeprovider/urlrouterprovider in Angular to tell it to serve the files to a different location?
Or do I change what I'm doing in Python?

The project directory looks like:

```
hellworld.py
requirements.txt
runp-heroku.py
procfile
Gruntfile.js
build/       //test code
  assets/
  index.html
  vendor/
bin/         //production code
  assets/
  index.html
  vendor/
src/         //original code
  assets/
  index.html
  vendor/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used Heroku, I usually get the Ubuntu server somewhere in the cloud and setup production manually. But the main point is that you production differs from development and you need a distinct config for production. You have two options:

- Configure Flask's static_path
- Or configure nginx to serve js/css you've built from the right dir

Comment: I wound up changing '/build' to static instead of changing the static path. Was unaware of the Flask static directory at the time I asked the question. Marking this answer as accepted as the first bullet was ultimately my answer. Thank you :D